# I want to display items from listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to display all the items in my listbox and print it as output.
 How can I do it?

I did try `listbox1.text` but it did not work.

Comment: can you put your code here, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can go with following code:

```
string finalString="";
foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
    {
        finalString = finalString + s;
    }
```

You can get all the member of listbox in variable "finalString".

Comment: Thanks alot, Your Code Work Thanks :)

Comment: @Jezreel, If you find it helpful then mark it as answer so it will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
string s = string.Empty;
while (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
  s = s + listBox1.Items[0] as string;
  // do something with s 
}
```

"s" will hold all the value member of the listbox.

Comment: You were initializing variable "s" each time so it won't hold old values and give only last value and also "s" is not accessible outside the loop. Please look into this

Comment: yes I've made the change, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try *joining* all the items into one string:

```
 string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,  
    listBox1.Items.OfType<Object>());
```

The only trick is that `listBox1.Items` is a collection which not implements `IEnumerable<T>`; so we have to put `OfType<Object>()` in order to convert the collection (to `IEnumerable<Object>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  var list = new ListItem[] {
           new ListItem("number 01","1"),
            new ListItem("number 02","2"),
            new ListItem("number 03","3"),
           new ListItem("number 04","4"),
            new ListItem("number 05","5")
        };

        lst.Items.AddRange(list);
        lst.DataBind();

        var strPrint = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        foreach (ListItem item in lst.Items)
        {
            strPrint.AppendLine(item.Text);
        }

        Response.Write(strPrint);
```